# Как правильно открыть COM порт

Tags: c#, com-порт

На столе лежит Gsm модуль RX 101 от "Телеофис", хочу пообщаться с ним из кода, но не получается.

Так же есть две программы для диагностики модуля, которые успешно связываются с модулем и успешно общаются по AT протоколу. То есть модуль рабочий.

А теперь что происходит когда я пытаюсь обратиться к модулю из кода - ничего!
То есть лампочка RX мигает, но ответа нет. При чем после закрытия программы которая успешно общалась с модулем, я могу из кода обращаться и модуль отвечает. Вот такая магия. Я полагаю что программы открывают порт с какими-то параметрами которые я не указываю в коде, но понятия не имею какие.

Вот код который пытается связаться с модулем:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var comPort = new SerialPort( "COM4", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One );

            comPort.Open();

            if ( !comPort.IsOpen ) throw new Exception();

            comPort.DataReceived += ComPortOnDataReceived; //событие, кстати, тоже не генерируется

            comPort.WriteLine( "AT \r\n" );

            Thread.Sleep( 3000 );

            var response = comPort.ReadExisting();

            Console.WriteLine( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( response ) ? "null" : response );

            comPort.DataReceived -= ComPortOnDataReceived;
            comPort.Close();
        }

        private static void ComPortOnDataReceived( object sender,
            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "received" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите какой нибудь программой (Например serial port monitor) какие параметры СОМ порта устанавливает родная программа. Возможно еще нужно указать `comPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff` или какой-то другой. Так же можно указать таймауты `comPort.ReadTimeout = 500`

Comment: И еще вы уверены что отправляете ему правильную посылку на которую он должен что-либо отвечать? Возможно вы правильно отправляете, но он ничего не должен отправлять в ответ.

Comment: @VadimPavlovich с виду посылка нормальная: на данную команду("AT") модем должен ответить "OK", вот только я писал в порт так: `serialPort.Write(string.Format("{0}\r", command));` ждем подтверждения по поводу корректности настроек соединения

Comment: @VadimPavlovich уверен, я же написал что после закрытии программы которая общалась нормально с модулем, из кода мне модуль отвечает, после следующего переоткрытия порта он снова молчит.

Comment: @VadimPavlovich свойство Handshake помогло, спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @VadimPavlovich: Опубликуете как ответ?

Comment: @anweledig пометьте тогда ответ как верный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данном случае необходимо установить кроме основных параметров инициализации СОМ порта еще и дополнительные

```
comPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
```

так как по умолчанию этот параметр установлен в `None`. Более детально про этот параметр можно посмотреть [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.handshake(v=vs.110).aspx).

Так же иногда могут возникать ситуации когда устройство долго отвечает на запрос(дольше стандартных значений). В таких случаях нужно изменять время ответа (искать в документации или экспериментировать с увеличением значений)

```
comPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
```

Я встречал устройства у которых время ответа по умолчанию равнялось 10с.

А вообще, в подобных ситуациях, когда не получается опросить устройство по СОМ порту и у вас есть родная программа опроса, запускать снифер СОМ-порта и смотреть какие основные и дополнительные параметры порта устанавливает эта программа.